# How to Order by relevance in a SQL query in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am using a SQL query for a specified and faster search in my Rails app, currently I have the following query that works wonderfully for gathering the data from the initial search:

`SELECT * FROM selected_tables 
    WHERE field1 LIKE '%#{present_param}'
    AND field2 LIKE '%#{present_param2}'`

And so on like that, with each LIKE line only appearing if the relevant parameter is present from the form.

So I am now able to get back a large amount of results from this query, but they're not ordered in any helpful way. I need some way of ordering the results based on their relevance to the original user input from the form, but I can't seem to find anything on google about it. Is there a way in SQL (specifically postgresql) that I can order the results based on this?

To be clear, when I say relevance I mean that a given search keyword should be in the title or company name for the result, not just present somewhere in the content.

For example: if you search "Sony" you get Sony Electronics first, not another listing containing Sony somewhere in the middle of its name.

Comment: https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "relevance" means here?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it via SQL? Depending on your project you might want to consider alternatives such as [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch).

Comment: I tried Elasticsearch, but I had the same problem and it took about 1.5 times as long
I'll add specifics, sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using a series of Case/When statements that were weighted with various integer scores to apply priority to my results. They work wonderfully and turned out something like this:

```
SELECT title, company, user, CASE 
  WHEN upper(company_name) LIKE '%#{word[0].upcase}%' THEN 3
  WHEN upper(company_name) LIKE '%#{company_name.upcase}%' THEN 2
  ELSE 0 END as score      
  FROM selected_tables
  WHERE company_name LIKE '%#{company_name}%'
  ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Had to tweak it a little for my needs, but other than that it works like a charm.